# What are the differences between ggpredict() and predictions()?

Tags: r, predict

I wanted to generate some predicted probabilities and I was recommended two commands: `ggeffects::ggpredict()` and `margin effects::predictions()`. However, some of the results seem similar (the conf.high) and other results seem different (the conf.low). What is going on here? Any insights would be helpful.

Here's an example:

```
logit <- glm(vs ~ mpg + cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + am + gear + carb, mtcars, family = "poisson")

library(ggeffects)
ggpredict(logit, terms=c("mpg")) %>% as_tibble()

library(marginaleffects)
predictions(logit, by=c("mpg")) %>% as_tibble()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions do different things by default.

1. `ggpredict()` with the `terms` argument computes predictions for each row of a data frame where `mpg` takes on values between 10 and 32, and all other variables are held at their means, including `am`, which is set to 0.41 even if it is presumably binary/categorical.
2. `predictions()` with the `by` argument computes predictions for each row in the actually observed data frame, and then takes the average of these predictions for each unique value of `mpg`.

In other words, `ggpredict()` reports predictions for “synthetic” data — hypothetical units which are exactly average along all dimensions except one. `predictions()` reports averages of predictions made on actually observed data.

It is easy to reproduce the same results as `ggpredict()` with `predictions()`, by using the `newdata` argument and the `datagrid()` function:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggeffects)
logit <- glm(vs ~ mpg + cyl + disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + am + gear + carb, mtcars, family = "poisson")

ggpredict(logit,
  terms = c("mpg")) |>
  data.frame() |> head()
#    x predicted std.error   conf.low conf.high group
# 1 10 0.2243430 1.2888961 0.01793916 2.8055810     1
# 2 12 0.2018065 1.0826924 0.02417384 1.6847077     1
# 3 14 0.1815340 0.9117794 0.03039834 1.0840915     1
# 4 16 0.1632979 0.7991309 0.03410037 0.7819915     1
# 5 18 0.1468937 0.7707321 0.03243060 0.6653523     1
# 6 20 0.1321375 0.8352217 0.02570893 0.6791536     1

predictions(logit,
  newdata = datagrid(mpg = seq(10, 34, by = 2), am = mean)) |>
  head()
# 
#  mpg    am Estimate Pr(>|z|)   S  2.5 % 97.5 %  cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec
#   10 0.406    0.224   0.2462 2.0 0.0179  2.806 6.19  231 147  3.6 3.22 17.8
#   12 0.406    0.202   0.1394 2.8 0.0242  1.685 6.19  231 147  3.6 3.22 17.8
#   14 0.406    0.182   0.0613 4.0 0.0304  1.084 6.19  231 147  3.6 3.22 17.8
#   16 0.406    0.163   0.0233 5.4 0.0341  0.782 6.19  231 147  3.6 3.22 17.8
#   18 0.406    0.147   0.0128 6.3 0.0324  0.665 6.19  231 147  3.6 3.22 17.8
#   20 0.406    0.132   0.0154 6.0 0.0257  0.679 6.19  231 147  3.6 3.22 17.8
# 
# Columns: rowid, estimate, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, vs, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec, gear, carb, mpg, am 
# Type:  invlink(link)
```

PS: this is not a logit model.